# Nativescript super and typescript

Tags: typescript, webstorm, super, nativescript

I included all the typescript source in my nativescript project, and webstorm compiled one of them, now I can't run the app.

I looked at the settings in the grunt file, which I have matched.

In timer.ios.ts the line looks like

```
    return <TimerTargetImpl>super.new();
```

Which compiles to (in WebStorm using typescript 1.4)

```
    return super.new.call(this);
```

However the (ts generated) code from tns create is

```
    return _super.new.call(this);
```

I can't find the difference with my typescript settings vs the ones in the grunt file.

I can't run it because I get

/app/tns_modules/timer/timer.js:17: JS ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected use of reserved word 'super'

I can fix it, but I would like to understand why I'm getting different code out of typescript.

Appreciate any help.

(Update)

Looking at the code that is causing the issue

```
class TimerTargetImpl extends NSObject {
    static new(): TimerTargetImpl {
        return <TimerTargetImpl>super.new();
    }                        
<snip>
```

It's using super in a static function, since it's static there is no instance so no super.

It seems like this new function should just be

```
 static new(): TimerTargetImpl {
        return new TimerTargetImpl();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

NativeScript is currently using v1.5.0 of typescript.      The only thing I can think of ES6 mode might make a difference.  The settings file for building shows:

"version": "1.5.0-beta",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": true,
        "outDir": "dist"
    },

Comment: Actually I think it's the lack of references, it doesn't have any reference to NSObject - so treats 'super' like a variable.  How does the nativescript build add references?

Comment: Actually I might be wrong about the version; I just ran TSC at my command line and I got  v1.5.0-alpha